# Find the limit of $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{2}{a_n}$, where $a_0=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$:

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + \dfrac{2}{a_n}$$

with $a_0=1$. How can I approach something like this? I'm relatively new to this kind of problems, so I would really appreciate it if you could explain what you're doing. I heard that this is actually easy to find **if** you know that a limit exists, but that's a big if. So that naturally gives rise to another question: How does one show that a limit exists? If a limit exists, how do I find it? If it doesn't, what then?

Comment: Hint: $a_{n+1}^2 = a_n^2 + 4 + \frac{4}{a_n^2} > a_n^2 + 4$

Comment: First note that $a_n\geqslant 1$ for all $n$, since $a_0=1$ and if $a_n\geqslant 1$ then $a_{n+1}=a_n+2/a_n\geqslant a_n\geqslant 1$. Now, $a_{n+1}/a_n = 1 + 2/a_n^2 > 1$, so $a_n$ is increasing. It remains to show that $a_n$ is bounded above, then it necessarily has a limit (its least upper bound).

Comment: As @lhf pointed out in his answer, the sequence actually is not bounded above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$. Then $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$ for all $n$.

Therefore, either $a_n$ has a finite limit (iff it is bounded) or it diverges to $+\infty$.

If $a_n$ had a finite limit $L$, then $L = L + \dfrac{2}{L}$, which cannot happen.

Therefore, $a_n$  diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Correct, but it wouldn't hurt to justify that $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$.

Comment: @Math1000 what do you want more than $a_n\ge 0$ as he did ? $a_{n+1}-a_n=2/a_n\ge 0$ is trivial enough.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. I was being needlessly pedantic.